# Rails schema.rb does not include new custom Postgres function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have just created a new custom Postgres function via usual migration.

```
class CreateBestBowlingFigureFunction < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    execute "CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ......"
  end
end
```

After the migration, this new function is not available in schema.rb.

As per the official doc, I use the command `db:schema:load` to create the schema before running my tests.

So, what is the best practice to create custom functions before running the tests?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`schema.rb` [does not handle](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#types-of-schema-dumps) (see section 6.2 of the Rails guides) views or custom functions. We have a view in our application and the schema does not work for it.

We use `structure.sql` instead as this properly sets up our view and, my sense is the same would apply here for custom functions. To use structure.sql instead of schema.rb:

> This is set in config/application.rb by the config.active_record.schema_format setting, which may be either :sql or :ruby.

You can also use a combination of `schema.rb` (for regular tables & index) and `structure.sql` (for custom functions). To setup this combo for test environments:

```
bundle exec rake db:schema:load
bundle exec rake db:structure:load
```

In this setup, note that the structure.sql has to be maintained manually while schema.rb will be maintained by Rails for you.

Comment: I am going to use a combination of schema.rb and structure.sql. And use `db:structure:load` to create the custom functions.

Comment: Nice! I haven't messed with the combo action before. Would love to know how it plays out (and might make my work life easier LOL).

Comment: Sweet! Thanks ... great to see.

Comment: "structure.sql has to be maintained manually" is not true, not in Rails 4 or 5 that is.  db/structure.sql is dumped every time you run rake db:migrate.